# Redirection of specific IP address to specific page in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, httpresponse

I have used below code to redirect specific IP address to specific page/website. It is working fine in Google Chrome but in Firefox and Internet Explorer, I am getting **Error**:
"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Code:

```
<?php

$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(preg_match("/192.168.1.187/",$visitor)) { 
header('Location: http://yahoo.com'); 
} 

else { 
header('Location: http://www.google.com'); 

}; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you sending the visitors to the same page? Seems like you created a loop of redirects.

Comment: @OscarBroman In if condition location is empty and requested webpage should open and its working fine for chrome.

Comment: there is a typo IMO in your code. After else portion parenthesis there is a semi-colon.

Comment: @user1788171 I have removed that and still its not working in Firefox and IE

Comment: Finally!!! The solution is to remove header('Location: http://yahoo.com'); from IF condition...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is an endless redirect to the URL , Clear your cookies once and try adding HTTPS before the URLs and give a shot.

Also add an `exit` or `die` after your `header` function.  That will do.

Like..

```
<?php

$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(preg_match("/192.168.1.187/",$visitor)) { 
header('Location: https://yahoo.com');
exit; //<-- Here 
} 

else { 
header('Location: https://www.google.com'); 
exit; //<-- Here
}; 
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(preg_match("/192.168.1.187/",$visitor)) { 
header('Location: ');

} 
else { 
header('Location: https://www.google.com'); 

} 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Tested the script in Nightly 29 (Firefox). I didnt get an error at all. But you should add `exit` behind each `header` so the script interrupts. And maybe you should add `www` in front of the yahoo homepage.